# Best practice to handle an impossible value for a static variable in Java?

Tags: java, error-handling, static, exit

(This question isn't about how it can be done, but rather how it should be done.)

I'm implementing a program that creates a decision tree. There are different ways the tree can be constructed, so I have a static variable 'type' that is assigned in the main function. In the Node class constructor, I have a switch statement that checks the value of this type variable and does something accordingly.

I want to know the best way to handle the case in which the value does not match any of the preset options (the 'default' case). This should be impossible and will probably never be executed, but I want to do it right nonetheless. If this case does happen, I want it to print a message and terminate the program.

I know I can do it by simply throwing an error there and catching it the main, but it doesn't seem intuitive for something that should never happen. Is "System.exit(1)," what I need?

```
public class Node {
    // some attributes

    public static int type;
    public static final int TYPE1 = 0;
    public static final int TYPE2 = 1;

    public Node(**arguments**){
        // do some stuff first

        switch(this.type){
            case Node.TYPE1:
                splitType1();
                break;
            case Node.TYPE2:
                splitType2();
                break;
            default:
                // unrecognized type
                System.err.print("Error: Unrecognized type");
                System.exit(1);
        }

        // do some more stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what exceptions are for.

Comment: @hot-licks: I understand that, but if it is a fatal error, it seems counter-intuitive to have to propagate it all the way back to main with try-catch-statements; especially for a case that is likely never to occur. Granted, in this case, Node's constructor is called directly from main, so it's not that far, but the question was meant in a more general way.

Comment: That's what happens when you take, say, a NullPointerException.  The default exception handler in the thread produces a stack dump, which is excellent for debugging.  And it all occurs pretty much for free -- no try/catch required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw an exception and *don't* catch it. Let it propagate all the way up. If something you consider to be impossible has happened, then you should have no confidence at all in your ability to "handle" it... the world is hugely screwed up.

`IllegalStateException` is *somewhat* appropriate for this, although you might also want to consider using `AssertionError`, if it's really *that* impossible. (Consider whether you want any code that catches plain `Exception` to try to handle this situation - if not, `Error` is appropriate.)

In this case, given that you've got a public static variable, it seems entirely feasible for *any* code to change this and put it in an invalid state. `IllegalStateException` is therefore more reasonable.

If, however, you changed the code so that the variable was private, and the methods which changed its value all validated that the value became either `0` or `1` before setting it, then an `AssertionError` would be more appropriate.

(I'd personally use an enum for something that can be one of a fixed set of values, mind you. That limits the ability of this to get messed up...)

Comment: This indeed seems the best way to handle it. Thanks for tip about enum too.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be to put the code in `Try` `Catch` and `Finally` block.
Set the flag in `default` case and handle the error accordingly in `finally` block.